# Return every employees department name

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

> Write function returning every employee's department name.
> Write a block printing all the employees name and department name in 20 dept.
> Function header:
> `Create or replace function empdnm (empno number) return varchar2 is`
>
> Try to write exception if there is no such empno.

I have tried the following code, but it shows me some errors, namely
`SQL  statment  ignored  and missing expression`.  What is the problem?

```
create or replace function empdnm (empno1 number) return varchar2 is 
deptname varchar (30);
BEGIN   
Select into deptname(select d.dname from dept d
join emp  e on  e.deptno=d.deptno
Where e.empno= empno1
)
exception
WHEN no_data_found THEN
dbms_output.put_line('no employee with no:'|| empno1);

return(deptname);
end;

BEGIN
FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM emp where dept_id = 20) loop
dbms_output.put_line( 'employee '|| r.emp_name  || ' is in department '||  empdnm(empno1) );
END loop;
end;
```

Comment: I don't know Oracle syntax inside out, but most dialects of SQL would expect something like `SELECT d.dname INTO deptname FROM dept d ...`.  Double check your Oracle syntax.  (This may be helpful; it may be wholly irrelevant.  Learning how to use the manual will be a long-lasting advantage.)

Comment: I suggest doing one thing at a time.  Specifically, start by making sure your function actually works.  What happens when you try "select empdnm(20) abc from dual"?

Comment: @dato - Are you trying to learn Oracle yourself or taking classes? If classes then run from your instructors ).

Comment: wow, they still using scott/tiger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
create or replace function empdnm (empno1 number) return varchar2 is 
   deptname varchar (30);
BEGIN   
   SELECT d.dname
   INTO   deptname
   FROM   dept d
   JOIN   emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
   WHERE  e.empno = empno1;

   return(deptname);
exception
   WHEN no_data_found THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('no employee with no:'|| empno1);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below one :

```
create or replace function empdnm (empno1 number) return varchar2 is 
   deptname varchar (30);
BEGIN   
   SELECT d.dname
   INTO   deptname
   FROM   dept d
   JOIN   emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
   WHERE  e.empno = empno1;

   return(deptname);
exception
   WHEN no_data_found THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('no employee with no:'|| empno1);
end;

BEGIN
FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM emp where dept_id = 20) loop
dbms_output.put_line( 'employee '|| r.emp_name  || ' is in department '||  empdnm(r.empno1) );
END loop;
end;
```